# How to move Chart.js legend?

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

Following [this example on their site](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#bar-chart-introduction), how would I move the "My First Dataset" legend to, say, below the chart instead of on top of it?

It doesn't appear to be a part of the documentation that I could find

Comment: http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#chart-configuration-legend-configuration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to mentioned http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#chart-configuration-legend-configuration, you need to add `legend` to `options`:

```
Chart.Bar(canvas, {
  data: data,
  options: {
    legend: {
        position: "bottom"
    }}
})
```

See working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gpccfv5p/).